# How to loop Android video?

Tags: android, video

I am doing frame by frame video decoding on Android using the `Mediacodec` and `MediaExtractor` classes, similar to [this](https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec).

When I read the `BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` I simply want to restart the whole sequence, but not sure what the proper way to do this is.

I want to avoid freeing up everything and restarting the video like it is ran the first time, if possible, as there is some lag for warming up the video, and it needs to play continuously from the start again.

So far I tried a `stop()`, then `start()`, but this crashed the app. Unfortunately the Android classes involved are very poorly documented, and a trial-and-error approach is very slow.

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why not use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)?

Comment: @CaptJak because I need to control the playback speed and exctract individual frames to a texture that is then rendered.